# Remove text from image

Tags: windows, images, privacy

I am looking for a program that can remove from an image a given text.

E.g. if given the image

[image]

and the text `Max` it should return something like:

[image]

where the text isn't visible anymore.

It should work on Microsoft Windows. Gratis is preferable.

Comment: tesseract-ocr and imagemagick (-draw rectangle) could be used as basic elements, but I don't a tool that does this out-of-the-box...

Comment: What's wrong with MS paint?

Comment: @Mawg I don't want to have to search for all occurrences of the text in the image myself

Comment: Sorry, that wan't clear from your question (or maybe I misunderstood). Obviosly some form of OCR is required. This could be a tricky one.

Answer (score 1):

I use Greenshot to add obscurification to parts of images. It's a free program compatible with Windows. It allows you to set how many boxes per pixel you want as well. Here below is an example using the image you provided above,

[image: Example Image]

You can also increase the pixel size to make it use bigger blocks,

[image: Example Image 2]

## [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) (free)

> Greenshot is a light-weight screenshot software tool for Windows with the following key features:
>
> - Quickly create screenshots of a selected region, window or fullscreen; you can even capture complete (scrolling) web pages from Internet Explorer.
> - Easily annotate, highlight or obfuscate parts of the screenshot.
> - Export the screenshot in various ways: save to file, send to a printer, copy to clipboard, attach to e-mail, send Office programs or upload to photo sites like - Flickr or Picasa, and others.
>
> …and a lot more options simplifying creation of and work with screenshots every day.
>
> Being easy to understand and configurable, Greenshot is an efficient tool for project managers, software developers, technical writers, testers and anyone else creating screenshots.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to specify which text I want the program to remove? ( i.e., I don't want to have to search for all occurrences of the text in the image myself )

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Unfortunately, no - maybe a combination of OCR and this software could help? I'm unaware, though, of software that does both.